# VIM Delete up until word/character

Tags: vim

In VIM, Given the following text:

"HelloWorld:**This is a test**"

If my cursor/caret is just after :, is there a command for me to delete up until the "?

So it would look like

"HelloWorld:"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, use the "till" motion.

```
dt"
```

means **d**elete un**t**il a **"**. There is also the "find" motion, which deletes up to *and including* the character. Both of these work in reverse if you capitalize them.

From `:h t`:

```
                            *t*
t{char}         Till before [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the
            right.  The cursor is placed on the character left of
            {char} |inclusive|.
            {char} can be entered like with the |f| command.
```